# MPLS Breakout via Azure

Tags: routing, azure

Would it be possible to actually breakout via Azure?

Say we have a MPLS network with 5 sites with an Express Route to Azure. Naturally we could configure the MPLS with a default route down the Express route for `0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0` but what would the actual `Next Hop IP` be?

Would you need a Virtual Firewall in Azure? I see the VMs have a gateway on their subnet within their vnet on `x.x.x.1` but I assume you can't just make this your next hop?

Comment: What do you mean by "breakout?" The routes are advertised via BGP dynamically to your edge provider. There are redundant paths, so the only "next hop" you need to know is the edge equipment sitting on your network. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-circuit-peerings

Comment: By breakout I mean traffic out to the Internet from my MPLS goes via Azure.